# Error: Exception in HostFunction: unordered_map::at: key not found

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, realm, expo-crypto

## React Native (iOS) & Realm: [Error: Exception in HostFunction: unordered_map::at: key not found]

**Description:**

I'm studying a React Native course, and the module uses Realm for data storage.
When I call `realm.write` and `realm.generate`, it works fine on **Android**, but it throws the following error on **iOS**:

```bash
[Error: Exception in HostFunction: unordered_map::at: key not found]
```

**Operating System and libraries:**

- macOS Ventura 13.4, Apple M1
- XCode 14.3 (14E222b)
- iPhone 12, iOS 16.4 (tried both Apple and Rosetta mode)
- "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.9.0",
- "expo": "~48.0.15",

**Code:**

```
function handleDepartureRegister() {
  try {
    // omitted for brevity

    realm.write(() => {
      realm.create('Historic', Historic.generate({
        user_id: user!.id,
        license_plate: licensePlate.toUpperCase(),
        description,
      }))
    });

    Alert.alert('Saída', 'Saída do veículo registrada com sucesso.');

    goBack();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    Alert.alert(
      'Erro',
      'Não foi possível registrar a saída do veículo.'
    );

    // omitted for brevity
  }
}
```

**Full code:**

https://github.com/ceduardogodoi/ignitefleet/blob/main/src/screens/Departure/index.tsx#L54

**Expected Behavior:**

It should not throw any error since it works on **Android**.

**Actual Behavior:**

It threw an error on **iOS**.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. I appreciate any help you can provide.

**What I've tried:**

- Run `pod install` on the **ios** folder
- Delete and create the simulator again
- Tried to run the simulator on both **Apple** and **Rosetta** mode
- Re-installing the **expo-crypto** library (and running `pod install` again)

Comment: You've got two key: value pairs `user_id: user!.id,` and `license_plate: licensePlate.toUpperCase()` but then a hanging var, `description` - what does that go with? Also this `user!` may be dangerous - force unwrapping an optional.. it's better to ensure it's not nil with a guard or if let statement to protect your code. Lastly, including links is fine as long as they have relevance. I don't see a correlation in this case. It's usually best to leave them out as if the link breaks (which they tend to do with age), it would invalidate whats being referred to.

Comment: Sorry, @Jay, the description is an object property shorthand from a React state (useState) that gets the value from the user input; I made it explicit in the code along with the correct link, my bad.
I know that force unwrapping is dangerous; I'll fix that too.

Comment: I am pretty sure you still still have to conform to Realm's requirements; [realm.create](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/crud/create/#crud---create---react-native-sdk) of `key: value` (per the error), unless I misunderstand the use case

Comment: The `generate` method and the object passed to it fulfill `realm.create` requirements (it works on **Android**).

I was able to fix that by downgrading `react-native-get-random-values` to `1.8.0`.

Comment: Oh how strange. It throws the error for me either version. Hmmm. Well, glad you got it working!

Comment: That's strange. Have you cloned my repo, or is it on a repo of yours?

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

- Remove the line for `react-native-get-random-values` from `package.json`
- Remove `package-lock.json`
- Remove `node_modules`
- Run `npm i` to install the dependencies
- Run `npm i react-native-get-random-values@1.8.0`